# What CMS would you use to recreate slashdot's distributed moderation system?

Tags: content-management-system, comments

Total, embarassing noob here, so here goes nothing: if you wanted to create a karma-based reputation system that treated user comments pretty much the way Slashdot does, but slashcode had never been invented, how would you go about it? Is there an OpenSource CMS that comes close to doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use [the real deal](http://www.slashcode.com/)?

**Edit:**

Somehow I missed the comment in the middle about Slashcode.  Sorry.

I'm still curious why you wouldn't use Slashcode, but what I'd probably do is give moderation to all logged-in users but give their moderation weighted values depending on their involvement and something akin to meta-moderation.

Thinking about it, SO and /. aren't that dissimilar in their community ranking strategies.  Karma and involvement having a lot to do with how often you receive moderation points....

**Extracted from comments:**

[Vanilla](http://getvanilla.com) with the [Community Moderation](http://lussumo.com/addons/index.php?PostBackAction=AddOn&AddOnID=412) add-on may be a good place to start.

Comment: OP is wondering what if slashcode wasn't there. Like programming BTTF-style for Johnny B. Goode.

Comment: Thanks! I considered using slashcode for the site I'm developing (or rather, having developed for me) but there just doesn't seem to be a very active community of slashcode developers out there I could hire. I am the ragingest noob in the world, and I need some handholding! A Wordpress patch, maybe?

Comment: Hm! Well with that in mind,the first place I'd personally look is Vanilla [http://getvanilla.com/].  Great community, respectable architecture.  This add-on [http://preview.tinyurl.com/5cp57t] may even meet your exact needs.

Answer (score 1):

Coming from the perspective of a software engineer, I would likely pick up PHP, MySQL, and a good development framework, and have at it.

It usually doesn't take to long to get a system to a working state if you know exactly what you need it to do. And the plus is that you get **exactly** what you want.

With open source tools like PHP and MySQL available, you are already so much of the way there that it may be easier to hand-code what you need rather than learning how to make X framework do it for you.